# UIImage is centred after resize

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

Code for iPhone app:

```
+(UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
  [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
  UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  return newImage;
}

CGSize sz = CGSizeMake( 200, 20 );
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
imageView.image = [Class imageWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] scaledToSize: sz];
```

The resized image is centred in imageView, I would like it to be left aligned (preferably top-left). How can I achieve this? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the contentMode to:

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTopLeft;
```

Comment: but then the image won't AspectFit your image view.... i don't think you can make an image AspectFit starting at top left corner just by setting the contentMode.

Comment: I think you can not use both content mode only one is allow either use UIViewContentModeTopLeft or  UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit.

Answer (score 5):

If you have set your imageView to have the content mode `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`, iOS will fit your image but it will also introduce transparent bars to the left and right if the fit is smaller than your width.

The solution is to let iOS fit the image, then figure out the new width and set the imageView's width with the new width.

```
    CGSize imgSize = contentProvider.image.size;
    CGRect frame = contentProviderViewOriginalFrame;

    if (imgSize.width > 0 && imgSize.height > 0)
    {
        double aspectRatio = (imgSize.width * 1.0) / (imgSize.height * 1.0);
        CGFloat newWidth = frame.size.height * aspectRatio;

        if (newWidth < frame.size.width)
        {
            frame.size.width = newWidth;
        }
    }
```